# Disable scrolling for PopupWindow's method showAsDropDown

Tags: android, popupwindow

I need to put PopupWindow on Layout in position that is out of screen.
I use showAsDropDown but it scroll Layout.
How to disable scroll for showAsDropDown?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Popup Window method in onCreate().It will do the trick.. The popup window starts when ever your activity get started..

have a look at this URL http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html